# Updating Repository to Revision

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Consider the following scenario.

I have an SVN repository. I have it checked out on my disk with custom checkout depth i.e., Only some of the directories are checked out onto my disk. For example, if branches has two folders A and B and under my custom depth, I only selected folder A to be checked out.

```
branches
  |___A
  |___B
    |___C
    |___D
Tags
Trunk
```

Folder B is used by another team. I want the data in only folder C under folder B. So, I right click in the repo location and select "Update to Revision".

In the Repo Browser that opens when I click on choose items button in the Update to Revision dialog

1. I have to expand all sub directories under A which have been checked out earlier so that the remaining sub directories which were not selected will be added
2. When I check only folder C under folder B and uncheck all other directories, they get deleted when I update.

How do I update to Folder C under folder B without updating Folder A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand question completely, but:

TortoiseSVN has cumbersome way for choose items for checkout, so I usually prefer use command line. It is easier and need only once

For example:

```
svn co --depth immediates http://host/repo/myrepo .
svn up --set-depth empty branches
svn up --set-depth infinity branches\A
svn up --set-depth empty branches\B
svn up --set-depth infnity branches\B\C
```

This should produce

```
branches (has only A, B)
  |___A (has all)
  |___B (has only C)
    |___C (has all)
tags (empty)
trunk (empty)
```

Comment: I have given Folder C as an example. Based on the user's need, s/he can update to any other folder also. Command line may not be suitable for this.

Comment: I can assure you, with command line s/he can update *any* folder. Just use its name in command :) Joke. I read question again and think I understand it now. TortoiseSVN can't do this, because it does not restore current state of sparse checkout. So, if you start 'Update to Revision' on branches, then you should manually restore state of A. But if you have B (but not complete), you can start 'Update to Revision' dialog only on this folder, so A will not be touched and preserve its content.